# Amcharts - Unable to load

Tags: angularjs, amcharts

I referred http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/TQxYB/ and tried to load in my project. I added script files in my index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
```

Added following code in html

```
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 362px;"></div>
```

And added following code in my controller

var chart;
     var legend;

```
 var chartData = [
 {
 "country": "Czech Republic",
 "litres": 301.9
 },
 {
 "country": "Ireland",
 "litres": 201.1
 },
 {
 "country": "Germany",
 "litres": 165.8
 },
 {
 "country": "Australia",
 "litres": 139.9
 },
 {
 "country": "Austria",
 "litres": 128.3
 },
 {
 "country": "UK",
 "litres": 99
 },
 {
 "country": "Belgium",
 "litres": 60
 }
 ];

 AmCharts.ready(function () {
 // PIE CHART
 chart = new AmCharts.AmPieChart();
 chart.dataProvider = chartData;
 chart.titleField = "country";
 chart.valueField = "litres";
 chart.outlineColor = "#FFFFFF";
 chart.outlineAlpha = 0.8;
 chart.outlineThickness = 2;
 chart.balloonText = "[[title]]<br><span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b> ([[percents]]%)</span>";

 // WRITE
 chart.write("chartdiv");
 });
```

For me not loading amchart - pie. Please suggest how to resolve?

Comment: Please make a fiddle that reproduces your problem. Your code looks right (though AmCharts.ready isn't necessary since it's mostly a `window.onload` under the hood), but we can't tell what else is wrong without seeing how the rest of your app is set up in angular.

Comment: I've tried you code in an fiddle and it all seems to work. Maybe there is something else in your code causing this problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/p3pxyao5/